# Show and hide one div add a time on button click using css issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap feature to make a functionality of showing/hiding one div at a time on button click like this

```css
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .if-not-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed) .if-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">
  <span class="if-collapsed">Add more div</span>
  <span class="if-not-collapsed">Remove more div</span>
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  //some content
  <button class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2">
    <span class="if-collapsed">Add 2nd last div</span>
    <span class="if-not-collapsed">Remove 2nd last div</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
  //Similar code as above
</div>
```

This allows me to put buttons inside collapsed div which I can click and add more div once the initial collapsed div is open. This allows me to add one div at a time.

If a user clicks add 2nd last div button and then 3rd last div button and so on.. and then goes and clicks remove 2nd last div button all other divs under it like 3rd last div and fourth last div remain displayed. Is there a way through CSS or Javascript that I can hide all successive div once the parent div is closed.

Comment: I do not really understand what you want. If preceding `div` elements are ment as "parent", they actually should be it in the DOM. Otherwise you might want the succeeding sibling css selector `~`.

Comment: I am sorry parent was not the right word to use. They are not actually related in any way. It's just that one thing comes after the other. And when the second div is heidden I want 3rd, 4th and 5th divs to be hidden as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want some multiple selectors rule like

```
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .if-not-collapsed, 
[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed) .if-collapsed,
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed~[data-toggle="collapse"]
{
  display: none;
}
```

`~` is the succeeding siblings selector. You can list multiple selectors by comma.

Be more specific like

```
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed~[data-toggle="collapse"]>.some-child
```

if your do not want do make the entire `div` elements invisible.

Comment: This did not work. The divs are not siblings of each other

Comment: Is there a way for me to say if `id="collapseExample2"` is not visible `collapseExample3` and `id="collapseExample4"` should not be visible?